# Page prevented back/forward cache restoration in lighthouse

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js, vercel, lighthouse

I'm developing a site with nuxt and hosting it on vercel.
Doing performance tests with lighthouse, locally (always on the builds), I have no particular problems, while on the real site, there is always the problem:
"Page prevented back/forward cache restoration".
Now I'm trying them all, for example, I set this up in the vercel.json file:

```
{
   "routes": [
     {
       "source": "/",
       "headers": [
         {
           "Cache-Control": "no-store"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

or this in the nuxt.config.ts file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   routeRules: {
     "/blog/**": {
       swr: 60 * 60,
       // or
       cache: {
         maxAge: 60*60
       }
     },
   }
});
```

and even this in the home script:

```
     window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       BroadcastChannel.prototype.postMessage = function () {
         throw new Error('BroadcastChannel cannot be used on cached pages.');
       };
     });
```

But nothing ever changes. What can I try?

Here is the full picture of the error:
[cacheError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4foJ.png)

Comment: There are some [best practices](https://web.dev/bfcache/) that you should follow to avoid this issue